# Is it possible to install 2 IP cameras in the same Wi-Fi network in a way that they are both visible by external networks, e.g. 3G mobile networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, ip, ip-camera

As just stated in the title, I am having trouble installing 2 IP cameras such as these pictured below. Basically, they both work with Wi-Fi network, but when I switch on 3G only one of them is visible by the IP camera Android app.

I have been told that it is not possible to have multiple IP cameras publicly visible, but only one of them, and that if you want to do so the configuration is highly complicated... is that true?

[image]

Comment: If both of them use UPnP to appear online and allow incoming connections, make sure they are using different ports. Two devices on one port is impossible to route.

Comment: They are on different IP and different ports...

Comment: Do you own two distinct external IP addresses? If not, then that's the issue I'm talking about. You can only assign one device to one port (unless you are using load based routing that requires switches, distinct servers etc.).

Comment: The first camera has 192.168.1.10 with port 81,the second 192.168.1.8 with port 3333.

Comment: These are local IPs. You can't access them unless you are in the same network. Make sure **both** ports are forwarded through your router or set up a VPN to access those local IPs through that.

Comment: As GiantTree says, you'll need to create two port forwards on your router - one for each camera IP and the respective ports you've configured thenm on. This should work perfectly if your Android app allows you to choose the port the cameras are on so you can connect to multiple cameras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its difficult to tell for sure as your cameras are very generic - It should be possible to run both cameras by having them on different ports and/or doing appropriate port-mapping on the router.

An alternative solution would be to get a router which is VPN server capable (you may well be able to convert your existing router to use dd-wrt or similar), then connect to your VPN from your phone and use the cameras as if you were on the LAN.  [ Note that you may need to use a dynamic DNS service as well so the VPN client on your phone can find the server.  ]  A good VPN system to use is OpenVPN

Comment: They indeed are on different ports and IP...